# Render Panels Overridden user profile template

Tags: 7, nodes, users, panels

I have overridden the user profile template using `Panels` module and want to render this overridden user profile in one of my custom module.

Actually I wanted to show "About Author", tab besides the "View" tab of article, which when clicked, will show overridden user profile.

For that I have created menu entry as follows:

```
function custom_menu() {
   $items = array();

    $items['node/%node/author'] = array(
        'title' => 'About Author',
        'page callback' => 'get_node_author',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    );

    return $items;
}
```

My function is as follows:

```
function get_node_author($node = NULL) {
    $account = user_load($node->uid);
    $account_view = user_view($account);
    return drupal_render($account_view);
}
```

But it is loading user profile in normal format and not the one which is customized using panels.

Any suggestion how can I achieve this?

Comment: Never tried, so I don't know. Out of curiosity, why are you doing this from a custom function anyway? Having built a large number of sites with Panels, I find the idea odd, and I'm wondering if you really should be solving this differently.

Comment: I just wanted to create one MENU_LOCAL_TASK (because it must be tab besides view, edit etc.) entry for node that shows customized author profile. Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Why not just re-create the user override you now have as a custom page in Panels? You can handle the menu directly from there.

Comment: Ok let me try out.

Comment: Ok, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you don't create a menu hook at all.

Just implement your desired layout in a custom panels page instead, and you can control the menu from there.

Comment: Hey, thanks it is working, one last thing, how can I create tab menu from it.

Comment: Got it, I selected menu tab.

Comment: Well, that was easy ;) Glad I could help. :)